# Collection list is returning duplicates

Tags: java, list, collections, set

Hey I am implementing this function.

```
private static HashMap<String, Set<String>> enrollments = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
private static Set<String> studentset;
/**
 * Enrolls a student into a unit.
 * 
 * @param unit
 * @param student
 */
public static void enroll(String unit, String student) {

    if(!enrollments.containsKey(unit)) {
        studentset = new HashSet<String>();
    }
    studentset.add(student);
    enrollments.put(unit, studentset);

}


/**
     * Gets a list of all students of a particular discipline. E.g. If discipline is
     * "ABC" then return a collection of all students enrolled in units that start
     * with "ABC", so ABC301, ABC299, ABC741 etc. This method is non-trivial so it
     * would help to first implement the helper method matchesDiscipline (below).
     * 
     * @param discipline
     * @return
     */

    public static Set<String> getStudents(String discipline) {

        Set<String> myList = new HashSet<String>();

        for (Entry<String, Set<String>> e : enrollments.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getKey().startsWith(discipline)) {

                myList.addAll(e.getValue());

            }
        }

        return myList;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnrollmentManager.enroll("CAB302", "James");
        EnrollmentManager.enroll("CAB403", "Ben");
        EnrollmentManager.enroll("CAB302", "James");
        EnrollmentManager.enroll("CAB403", "Morgan");
        EnrollmentManager.enroll("CAB404", "Sam");
        System.out.println(EnrollmentManager.getStudents("CAB3"));
    }
```

The problem im having is 'myList' is outputting [Morgan, James, Ben]. Where the correct answer would be [James]. Where am I going wrong? Sorry if its a simple solution im new to Collections.

Comment: can you paste your `enroll` function?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the expected output be James? as `e.getKey().startsWith(discipline)` will match your input "CAB3", and as per your data only James seem to be matching it.

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: IMO it would make more sense if the map was `<Student, List<Units>>`

Comment: @Sam did your issue resolve?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you are using a static `studentSet` variable. Let me dry run your code.

What you are doing here is that you are creating a new set when key is not found, otherwise you are using existing set, which is your static member.

```
if(!enrollments.containsKey(unit)) { 
    studentset = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

`EnrollmentManager.enroll("CAB302", "James");` will create a new set, let's say set1 and assign it to static member studentset. studentset after this step {James}.

`EnrollmentManager.enroll("CAB403", "Ben");` will create a new set, let's say set2 and assign it to static member studentset. studentset after this step {Ben}

`EnrollmentManager.enroll("CAB302", "James");` will **NOT** create  a new set and use current value of studentset i.e. set2. studentset after this step {Ben,James}

`EnrollmentManager.enroll("CAB403", "Morgan");` will **NOT** create  a new set and use current value of studentset i.e. set2. studentset after this step {Ben,James,Morgan}.
And since your map has a reference to this static member, whenever you retrieve , you are getting the static member values..

What you should do is instead of using the static set member, you can use a function variable.
And change your condition like this:

```
Hashset<String> studentset = null;
if(!enrollments.containsKey(unit)) { 
    studentset = new HashSet<String>();
}else{
   studentset = enrollments.containsKey(unit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your enroll method like below to work:

```
public static void enroll(String unit, String student) {

    if(!enrollments.containsKey(unit)) {
        studentset = new HashSet<String>();
        enrollments.put(unit, studentset);
    } else {
        studentset = enrollments.get(unit);
    }
    studentset.add(student);

}
```

**Your mistake:** you have a static reference `private static Set<String> studentset;` which in your case is used to add a new student in the previous entry of map when `!enrollments.containsKey(unit)` returns false. Best practice is to make this a local variable and define it in enroll method.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your static variable `studentset` and you are adding to that set even if there is `studentset` already in the map for a `unit`. You should add to the already existing set in the map if a key is found.

If you are using Java 8 or higher you can simply do it in one line :

```
enrollments.computeIfAbsent(unit, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(student);
```

And you don't need a `studentset` static field at all.